# Python/Jython parse e-mail

Tags: python, jython

I have parsed en e-mail message using Jython to get the e-mail mesages body value.
Now I have the body value and I'd like to extract the following text from it.

The body contains text and I would like to extract the following text:

There are rows found in the body:

```
 [type]: mail
 [category]: Values
 [service]: testing
 [description]: Testing out automapping of email
 Line break Testing out automapping of email
 Line break Testing out automapping of email
```

Now I would like to extract all the value after the [description]:
Is this possible?
I tried this:

```
desc = '[description]:'
res = findall("{}.*".format(desc), body)[0]
```

Comment: You said that the body contains HTML **and** text. Where's the HTML?

Comment: Sorry updated question:

Comment: Ok using this: res = findall("%s.*" % '[description]:', body) I get only one row.. how do I include all rows of the text?

Comment: Updated question using only text values and multiple lines

Comment: Why not [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex possible solution, but consider @StefanNch suggestion:

`\[description\]:((?:.+\n?)*)`

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\[description\]:((?:.+\n?)*)')
test_str = u" [type]: mail\n [category]: Values\n [service]: testing\n [description]: Testing out automapping of email\n Line break Testing out automapping of email\n Line break Testing out automapping of email"
subst = u""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)

re.search(p, test_str)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sX1tV2/2)

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion but I can't use BeautifulSoup because of products limitation. Ok this will output a value of true when printed.. how can I print the text found after [description]: ?

Comment: print re.findall(p, text) this will print wanted result except it also prints the [description]: when it should only print the value after that. Any clues?

Comment: I updated answer using a capturing group, so it only captures text after `[description]:`